# Conclude what kind of matrix $A$ is

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

If $A \in M_n(R)$ is a symmetric matrix and if $tr(A^2)=0$ then conclude what kind of a matrix $A$ is.
Is it zero, or non-zero, or does it have zero as an eigenvalue, or is there at least one non-zero eigenvalue?

I am not sure how to even approach this problem. Ideas are appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Using the spectral theorem, $A$ is diagonalizable with real eigenvalues. Therefore, since $\textrm{tr}(A^2)=0$, the sum of the squares of the eigenvalues of $A$ is zero. Hence, $A$ has zero as unique eigenvalue. Finally, since $A$ is diagonalizable, $A=0$.